# I get the error "must declare the scalar value @time" for this code. Need a help for fixing it

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I get the error "**must declare the scalar value @time**" for this code. I just wanted to import local time and store it in the table. 
`Logged_in` column's data type is `datetime`

```
obj.conn.Open();

DateTime localdate = DateTime.Now;

string time = localdate.ToString("MM'/'dd'/'yyyy HH':'mm':'ss.fff");

string loggedintime = "INSERT INTO UserAccountTable(Logged_in) values (@time)";

obj.cmd.Connection = obj.conn;

obj.cmd.CommandText = loggedintime;

obj.cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

obj.conn.Close();
```

Comment: you need to use `SqlParameters`!

Comment: @omriman12 How ?.. i need to get local date and time

Comment: posted an answer

Comment: @omriman12 I'm new. Please explain the code with comments.

Comment: Look at the answer i posted..... i wrote the entire code

Comment: What's wrong in this ?


using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename="E:\Visual Studio Applications\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\UsersDB.mdf";Integrated Security=True"))

Comment: `What's wrong in this ?` That is a different question. Please raise a new post for that.

Comment: What is the column type of `Logged_in` in the database?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the parameter:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", time );
```

And for the love of god, dispose your connection:

```
string commandText = "INSERT INTO UserAccountTable(Logged_in) values (@time)";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", time );


    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        Int32 rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Console.WriteLine("RowsAffected: {0}", rowsAffected);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

And also you do not need to parse your date to a string!

Simpley use the `DateTime`, make sure its a date field in your db !

Comment: Do NOT use the lazy and error-prone [addwithvalue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). And if you suggest not to get the user-entered value as a string, then that should be reflected in your code.

Comment: It is problematic to suggest that the OP uses `time` as a parameter rather than the proper variable type.